# classmethod built-in function - Can't understand a statement from Documentation

Tags: python

Under the [classmethod()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod) built-in function in the 2nd chapter itself of the [Python Standard Library](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html), I was confused with the two statements, that I'm quoting here:  -

> A class method receives the class as implicit first argument, just
>   like an instance method receives the instance.

Ok, till this part I was clear enough, that a `classmethod` is specific for a class, so, instead of taking `self` as an implicit argument, which represents an instance of that class, we use `cls`, which represents the class itself, and binds that `classmethod` to the class..

Now, here's another statement later on in this topic which confused me: -

> If a class method is called for a derived class, the derived class
>   object is passed as the implied first argument.

Now, what that is supposed to mean? Is it trying to say that, we actually pass `an object` to a `classmethod` when used in this situation? But doesn't this contradicts the first statement itself.

Can anyone make me understand, how those two statements go hand-in-hand without contradicting each others??

I tried to find out some resource, but couldn't find an `example`, demonstrating the `second case`..

Comment: derived class means child-class, not instance-object

Comment: @fanlix.. I know that, but its written: - `derived class object`

Comment: A class is an object as well. The sentence is not about an instance object, but about a class object.

Comment: @glglgl.. Ok.. I could have never interpreted that statement in this way.. thanks :)

Comment: Can the downvoter leave a comment here. So that his down vote is more meaningful??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A class is a fully-featured first-class object, just like instances of that class are (though they are obviously not the same objects). When we say a `classmethod` of `class C` receives the "class object" as first argument, we say it receives an object which represents a, not an object for which `isinstance(<the object>, C)` is true. The latter is called (class) *instance*, "class object" is reserved for objects which *are* classes.

The second sentence simply clarifies that if the class method is called on a derived class, the class method receives that derived class (AKA "the derived class object"), to enable polymorphic behaviour. For example (Python 3, because f..k old style classes):

```
class C:
    x = 1

    @classmethod
    def m(cls):
        return cls.x

class D(C):
    x = 2

print(C.m()) # 1
print(D.m()) # 2
```

Comment: @delnan.. Thanks delnan.. That clarifies my doubt.. :)

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, a class object is an instance of its metaclass (`type` by default).

Answer (score 2):

```
class A(object):
    @classmethod
    def x(cls): return cls

class B(A):
    pass

print B().x()
```

Here, I call `A.x()` via its subclass `B`.

Thus, the class object `B`, derived from `A`, is returned.

Comment: @glglgl.. That means, we can call `classmethod` of base class through derived class object??

Comment: Exactly this is the case. The class object of the actual instance wil be used. Even `B.x()` would be viable, because class methods can be called via the class and via an instance of that class.

Comment: @fanlix.. Yeah tried that.. Both of them gave the same result.. Thanks fanlix  :)